Mi navegador no reconoce un archivo scss

Me encontré con este error, estoy haciendo un curso de desarrollo web en el que se utiliza Sass. Todo iba bien hasta que tenía 4 archivos .scss:

_footer.scss
_header.scss
_iconos.scss
_navegación.scss

Después agregué otro archivo:

_anuncios.scss

Y ya estaba referenciado este mismo junto a los otros de la siguiente manera en el archivo app.scss:
@import 'layout/header';
@import 'layout/footer';
@import 'layout/navegación';
@import 'layout/anuncios';
@import 'layout/iconos';

Pero, sorpresa, al hacer cambios en el archivo _anuncios.scss, estos estilos no se reflejan en mi proyecto. Incluso cuando inspecciono los estilos dentro de los navegadores, solo me aparecen 4 archivos:

_footer.scss
_header.scss
_iconos.scss
_navegación.scss

Es decir, el archivo _anuncios.scss no es reconocido. No sé si es por eso mismo que no se aplican los cambios en mi proyecto.
De antemano, voy empezando en esto del desarrollo web. Muchas gracias de antemano y espero puedan ayudarme.

Hasta donde sé, los navegadores no soportan directamente scss. SCSS es un preprocesador y debes compilarlo en un CSS regular, que es lo que el navegador espera.

Compila el proyecto de nuevo, y si no, el archivo como tal, parece que tu main es app.scss. Recuerda que la página como tal es la encargada de cargar la hoja de todos modos.
